# How to stop viewpager fragments from loading data

Tags: android

I am working on Android project. I have a tablayout and viewpager with 100 tabs and each tab having fragment. Each fragment is individually making a server call to fetch data. Problem is when I click on far away tab like for instance click tab 10 while on tab 1, few fragments in the middle start their lifecycle and start to fetch the data. I have seen usually there are 6 network calls being made when I do so even though I have set offscreenPageLimit to 1 as well.

I understand its fine for viewpager to load data of 2 adjacent fragments(with offscreenPageLimit = 1), but its loading 6(or more). I don't want the middle fragments to start loading data. Is there a way to achieve this? I think this is happening because when I tap on fragment 10, to move from fragment 1 to 10, viewpager is going in scrolling smoothly and for fragments of a second, it shows few fragments just before the target fragment and those fragments start their lifecycle methods as those are displayed.

Tried to put offscreenPageLimit = 1, but its still 6 fragments are loading data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setUserVisibleHint method in Fragment and Call the network request into this method。